# Laravel 5 - Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 5.5.4 Invalid domain name

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I was trying to use Laravel Mail service to send an email from my WAMP localhost. And I got the following error:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 5.5.4
>   Invalid domain name "

The code to send the email is as follows:

```
public function sendTo($user, $subject, $view, $data = [])
{
    \Mail::queue($view, $data, function ($message) use ($user, $subject) {
        $message->from(\Config::get('config.admin_email'), \Config::get('config.admin_name'));
        $message->to($user->email, $user->full_name)->subject($subject);
    });
}
```

In .env, the setting is:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.server.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I have tried to change `tls` to `ssl`, port number to 465, or 25. None of these worked.

The mail server I am using is Microsoft Exchange server.